# Using appsettings key in Display attribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have some hardcoded value which I want to change to read the value from web.config.

```
[Display(Name = "SomeValue")]
```

I tried with

```
 [Display(Name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeValue"].ToString())]
```

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this *properly*, you would create a new attribute to use instead of `DisplayAttribute`, and a new `ModelMetadataProvider` which correctly reads that attribute and the other display attributes.

To do it simply, you create a new `HtmlHelper` extension that reads the attribute, then access Web.config to find that AppSettings key, and returns the value.

**Model**

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
    [Display(Name ="IdColText")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Extension**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ProjectName
{
    public static class DisplayConfigNameExtension
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString DisplayConfigNameFor<TModel, TResult>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression)
        {
            ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>());
            string configName = metadata.DisplayName;
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configName]);
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```cs
@model SomeClass

// The following is required for the HtmlHelper extension
@using ProjectName;

@Html.DisplayConfigNameFor(m => m.Id)
```

This will also work if using the `DisplayNameAttribute` instead of `DisplayAttribute`, and should also work for classes with `MetadataTypeAttribute`.